# Class attributes do not show on debuglement.nativeElement while testing an angular 4 component

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine

I have a simple angular component where I add a class to an html tag based on a condition:

```
<td><i ngClass="{{ iconType }}" aria-hidden="true" ></td>
```

It works fine, I can see the expected icon appear when I render the page in my browser. However, when I try to write a test, I cannot  doesn't have any class.
Here is my test:

```
describe('TableRowComponent', () => {
let tableRowFixture: ComponentFixture<TableRowComponent>;
let component: TableRowComponent;

beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [
            FlipperModule.forRoot({
                provide: 'flippers',
                useValue: []
            }),
            MomentModule
        ],
        declarations: [
            TableRowComponent
        ],
        schemas: [
            CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA
        ],
        providers: [
            {
                provide: FlipperService,
                useValue: {
                    isOn: () => true,
                    isOff: () => false
                }
            }
        ]
    });

    tableRowFixture = TestBed.createComponent(TableRowComponent);
    component = tableRowFixture.componentInstance;
    const twoDays = 172800000;
    component.deployable = {
        'name': 'ems-event-segmentation-staging',
        'lastDeployDate': '2017-06-02T15:05:09Z',
        'type': 'service',
        'syncDelay': twoDays,
        'commitLag': 2
    };
});

    it('should display the expected icon based on the iconType property', () => {
        const icon: DebugElement = tableRowFixture.debugElement.query(By.css('i'));
        console.log(icon.nativeElement);

});
```

});

My log output is:

```
LOG: <i _ngcontent-c30="" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

How come the class property isn't visible here?

Comment: try `class="{{ iconType }}"`

Comment: @handris Shouldn't the syntax be `[ngClass]=[iconType]`? Could you try this?

Answer (score 0):

Since a class is `ngClass` directive that accepts an expression, it won't be available right after component compilation.

```
  tableRowFixture.detectChanges();
```

should be performed before executing a query on debug element.